# Find the MVUE of $1-e^{-2\theta}$

Tags: umvue

I'm given the following question and I have to choose one of the four possible answer:

Let $X_1$ be a sample of size $n=1$ from distribution whose p.d.f. is:
$$ f(x;\theta)=\theta e^{- \theta x} \mathbb{1}_{(0, +\infty )} (x)$$
Then, a MVUE of $1-e^{-2\theta}$ is:

1. $\mathbb{1}_{(2,+\infty)}(X_1)$
2. $X_1$
3. $1-e^{-X_1}$
4. $\mathbb{1}_{(0,2)}(X_1)$

Where for $\mathbb{1}$ one intends the indicator function.
I know how to find a MVUE, but I don't get the point of evaluate a MVUE of something without the X term.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here, $\theta$ is a parameter and $f(\theta)=1-e^{-2\theta}$ is a function of this parameter. Since you don't know the value of the true parameter, you'll estimate it. And, estimators will use samples, i.e. $X_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among these four options, only (4) is an unbiased estimator of $1 - e^{-2\theta}$ (it is straightforward to check). By Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, it is also the UMVUE because $n = 1$.